# Do I need to resign apk every time I make a change?

Tags: android, apk, keytool, jarsigner

I am making my first app and just signed and did all that to make a official signed, non debugging apk. Now, if I want to make a small change, do I need to go through all the resigning again, and use the same key, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must resign and you should use the same key if you want your users to be able to upgrade without difficulty (if you change the key it is considered a different app).

You should also update the version info in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to use the same key every time you submit to the market. Make sure you keep your keystore in a safe place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to sign with the same key to be able update the app on the market. further more, if you lose your keystore - you will not be able to update the app anymore. So back it up somewhere safe, and preferably on three more places.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You have to resign and use the same key.
Also need Update in the manifest.